# make recipe to link to avoid undefined reference to WinMain@16

Tags: makefile, g++, mingw, undefined-reference, winmain

Thanks for taking my question. I have spent many hours checking posts on this but I still need help. Thanks for being patient with me :)

I have a class of midi functions that calls the Widows multimedia API.

When I compile my class Midf.h by itself at the command line it compiles and works:

```
g++ -Wall Midf.h Midf.cpp midftest.cpp -lwinmm -o midftest2.exe
```

I have written a makefile to include these functions in a larger program.

My recipe for building the Midf.o is as follows:

```
 Midf.o: Midf.cpp Midf.h
              g++ -Wall Midf.cpp -lwinmm
```

At this point I get the following error:

```
g++ -Wall Midf.cpp -lwinmm
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o): In function `main':
e:\p\giaw\src\pkg\mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src\bld/../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/main.c:91: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:21: recipe for target 'Midf.o' failed
make: *** [Midf.o] Error 1
```

I have read that Mingw does not support wmain, but there is a way around that by making sure that main is defined properly outside of a namespace.  I am not sure how to do that.

I would be glad to post the entire makefile, my file that contains main(), Midf.h Midf.cpp or any other file in the source code to find the problem.

By the way, this is a console program and I have tried building it with MinGW and with Cygwin.

Thanks again for everyone willing to help!

Comment: If you're trying to compile object files separately your recipe for `Midf.o` is incorrect, gcc thinks you are trying to compile and link a complete program, you need to add the `-c` flag to compile without linking.

Comment: Thanks user657267. I added the -c flag, which shows I have linker errors.  All of my .o files compile now, including Midf.o

Comment: Thanks user657267. I added the -c flag, and all of my .o files compile now, including Midf.o. Unfortunately the compiler returns  lots of linker errors in Midf.o. Midf.cpp includes Midf.h and mmsystem.h but the compiler is reporting undefined references to the windows Midi API functions. I have tried adding -I/path/to/mmsystem.h and even -I /to/libwinmm.a but get the same error:
Midf.o:Midf.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to     `midiOutOpen@20' 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Midf.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.ctors'
Any ideas?

Comment: If the very first example you posted above works, then compiling each `.cpp` file separately with `g++ -c` followed by `g++ Midf.o midftest.o -lwinmm` once when all units have been compiled should work as well, you might want to post your complete Makefile.

Comment: It seems I have two different issues:

Comment: continued ... I either get a undefined reference to WinMain@16 if I leave out the -c flag, or I get undefined references to the mmsystem.h functions if I put it in. How do I post the Makefile since it has a character count limit? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Something's not right if you're including your `.h` files in the compilation process, either they only contain declarations and `inline` functions in which case they don't need to be compiled, or they contain non-`inline` function definitions etc. and aren't header files at all. Dump your code and Makefile somewhere like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com).

Comment: I think there is a linker problem in my recipe to make Midf.o It builds but still has problems. Here is my rule:  Midf.o: Midf.cpp Midf.h
                 g++ -Wall -c Midf.cpp -I /cygdrive/c/MinGW/include/ \
                  -I /cygdrive/c/MinGW/lib/  -lwinmm

 Here are the errors:                 Midf.o:Midf.cpp:(.text+0x4a8): undefined reference to `midiOutClose@4'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Midf.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.ctors'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Hi. I have pasted the makefile, Midf.h, Midf.cpp and the make output on pastebin.com [link](http://pastebin.com/nshbFjvg) [link](http://pastebin.com/UmMLwcvN) [link](http://pastebin.com/t4AacK4c) [link](http://pastebin.com/EZkP8Ebp) Hopefully that will be enough. I think the problem lies in the first link on lines 21-22. Thanks!

Comment: Library flags are for linking, not compiling, move the `-lwinmm` flag to the recipe for `M110F14.exe` (after `$(OBJS)`)

Comment: Also your entire Makefile can be replaced with something like [this](http://pastebin.com/9BMU5Cjb) (assuming your main exe source file is named `M110F14.exe.cpp`). The implicit make rules can handle the recipes for you and gcc's auto-dependency flags allow you to strip out the dependency crud. You shouldn't need to specify the include and library paths if you have your compiler set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much! That solved the problem. It compiled without a warning or error. Thanks also for the additional help on the Makefile!

Comment: Great answer and terrific help - Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn my comments into an answer:

If you want to perform separate compilation you have to tell gcc not to link your objects by passing the `-c` flag.

Your second problem was not passing the libraries during linking, passing them during compilation has no effect.